# How to change a block texture but not the item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

i changed the texture of the chest of minecraft so it is invisible for a map of mine, but as the item is the block itself it is invisible in the inventory as well, i searched and there is no chest in the item textures folder, is it possible to create a item.chest file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks in Minecraft are made out of voxels with individual sides.

The stone block texture is flat. In order to put it in 3D space, it has to be manipulated somehow.

[image: stone block texture]
[image: stone block]

It is mapped to a voxel by setting each face to the texture. (Stone uses a random rotation, but that's irrelevant). This image is used as both the block in-game and the item model.

---

Blocks like the chest and hopper are more complex, as they don't fill the whole block and have unique sides.

The block is flattened out, and stitched together by hard-coded constraints. This is like when you have a piece of paper that you can fold out into a cube, but without the glue tabs and with image manipulation instead of folds.

[image: chest texture]
[image: chest voxel]

As I said earlier, the mapped voxel is what is used for the item model. This means it will look the same in your inventory as it does when placed. So if you want to place an invisible block, the item has to be invisible too.

### TL;DR - No, you can't make an 'item.chest' file.